# HTMLParser does not parse the entire input

Tags: class, python-3.x, html-parsing

I wrote some scripts in python, but never really got in contact with classes. Now I need one because of setting up a html parser (from sniplets in the web). It works fine, but the last data-string is missing. It seems the function did not run the last time.

My code was the following:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        #reset
        self.reset()        
        #options
        self.strict = False
        self.convert_charrefs= True
        #create empty list for all my stored data
        self.fed = []               
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print ('D:', data)        #as you might see in output of a run, string after last tag is not added, because function did obviously not run
        self.fed.append('-'+data)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def process_description(desc):
    s = MyHTMLParser()
    s.feed(desc)
    return s.get_data()

text_html='first <br />second<br />third'
text=process_description(text_html)  
print (text)
```

Output:

```
D: first 
D: second
-first -second
```

The text_html string is not procesed by the function process_description() completely. As it can be seen in the output the substring ("third") after the last html tag is not processed by the handle_data() function. There must be something syntactically wrong. What is wrong?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question - what exactly is the problem? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subclass `.__init__` should just call the baseclass `.__init__` instead of copying what you think it does and only do extra what is really specific to the subclass.

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(strict = False, convert_charrefs= True)
    #create empty list for all my stored data
    self.fed = []
```

What is actually wrong is that you forgot to call .close() after done feeding.  From the doc: "Force processing of all buffered data as if it were followed by an end-of-file mark."

```
def process_description(desc):
    s = MyHTMLParser()
    s.feed(desc)
    s.close()  # <-- added #
    return s.get_data()
```

After closing, the result is what you wanted and expected.

```
D: first 
D: second
D: third
-first -second-third
```

(The space is in the input.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining this really basic mistake I copy&pasted from the web. I just wondered before, because I thought, that there were some keywords like constructor and destructor. Are these the termini or am I wrong again? May you recommend  another title of the question, so that it is useful and findable for other persons? (e.g. Solved: HtmlParser, parsing is not done completely.

Comment: Or "Solved: HTMLParser does not parse the entire input."  (Also, mark answer as accepted ;-).  (I do not understand question in "keywords ... termini".)